# Can we separate justice from theology in Christianity? And if we do, is this right?

Tags: justice, martin-luther-king-jr

Dr. Martin Luther King in one of his major speeches said:

> I want to say to you tonight, that I intend to keep these issues mixed because they are mixed. Somewhere, we must see that justice is indivisible, injustice anywhere is a threat to justice everywhere and I have not fought long and hard against segregated public accommodations to end up at this point of my life, segregating my moral concerns.

It seems likely that he was urged to keep justice and so politics separated from his religious commitments.

Given the answer that this question has received, it's likely that I haven't been focuses enough in what I'm asking. So I'm adding the following to make it clear what I'm asking:

**Q. Was Dr. Martin Luther King urged by the clergy he knew and was mentored by to keep his sermons and speeches clear of controversial political subjects, such as Imperialism, Economic Exploitatuon and Racism?**

And

**Q. In the wider Christian community, but in particular for pastors within the Catholic and Baptist dispensations are pastors are expected to keep questions of justice, and hence politics, separate from that of theology and then to focus wholly on the latter? And if so - is this right?**

It should go without saying, that I am no pastor; in fact, I'm not a Christian. My interest in Christianity simply arises from being born in what was once a major Christian country and that Christ is a major figure in Islamic Prophetology and a wider interest in religion in general.

An anecdotal evidence, I note that in the only church service that I have attended and which was at Christ's Mass, the Anglican vicar spoke about the climate of disinformation and the turmoil caused by Brexit. This seems political - to me.

Comment: FYI, you keep misspelling his name. It's Luther with an e, not an o. And put the Jr at the end. And the justice tag already existed.

Comment: Your two bold questions are both worthy in their own right, but they need to be delt with separately. Please choose which one you want to ask here and then ask the other one in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

King's Charlottesville speech is about racism, Vietnam and oppression of the poor. If you add a few of the preceding lines of the speech to your quote this becomes clear:

> May I say in conclusion that there is a need now, more than ever
> before, for men and women in our nation to be creatively maladjusted.
> Mr. Davis said, and I say to you that I choose to be among the
> maladjusted, as my good friend Bill Coughlin said there are those who
> have criticized me and many of you for taking a stand against the War
> in Vietnam and for seeking to say to the nation that the issues of
> Civil Rights cannot be separated from the issues of peace. I want to
> say to you tonight that I intend to keep these issues mixed because
> they are mixed. Somewhere we must see that justice is indivisible,
> injustice anywhere is a threat to justice everywhere and I have fought
> too long and too hard against segregated public accommodations to end
> up at this point in my life, segregating my moral concerns.

When he talks about these issues being mixed, he means things like:

- Poor men, and especially African Americans, were drafted at significantly higher percentages than rich white men. [See Blacks and the Draft: A History of Institutional Racism](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2783700?seq=1)
- segregation of facilities, services, and opportunities such as housing, medical care, education, employment, and transportation in the United States along racial lines
- The [civil rights movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_rights_movement) in the United States, a decades-long struggle by African Americans and their like-minded allies to end institutionalized racial discrimination, disenfranchisement and racial segregation

He is not talking about separating religion from politics. This is not how "separation of church and state" is interpreted in the US.

In the US, involvement of religious leaders and organizations is governed by rules for political activity that apply to all nonprofit organizations (including churches and other religious groups) that are exempt from taxation under section 501(c)(3) of the Internal Revenue Code. The prohibition on political campaign intervention did not become part of the Internal Revenue Code until 1954, when an amendment to section 501(c)(3) was introduced by then Senator Lyndon B. Johnson during a Senate floor debate on the 1954 Internal Revenue Code.

The First Amendment provides that “Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion or prohibiting the free exercise thereof ...” Although the Internal Revenue Code prohibition against political campaign intervention may burden the exercise of religion to the extent that a religious organization must choose between the receipt of the benefits of tax exemption and intervention in a political campaign, not every burden on religious exercise is constitutionally prohibited.

Religious organizations are prohibited from participating or intervening, directly or indirectly, in a political campaign on behalf of or in opposition to any candidate for
elective public office.

They are however, not prohibited from discussions of issues that are not linked to support for or opposition to candidates. The fact that candidates may align themselves on one side or another of an issue does not restrict the ability of religious organizations to engage
in discussions of that issue.

Since you mentioned an observation on the Anglican church, in the UK the situation is constitutionally very different. The Queen is head of the State, the Armed Forces and the Anglican Church, and all UK citizens (whether they are Anglican or not) pay taxes for the Anglican church. The Church of England has a large endowment of £8.9 billion which generates approximately £1 billion a year in income (2019)[1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2783700?seq=1), this is their largest source of revenue. This is a constitutionally established state religion but other faiths are tolerated (although they do not receive the same preferential treatment). Besides the British monarch being the Supreme Governor of the Church of England, the church has actual political power: 26 bishops (Lords Spiritual) sit in the upper house of government, the House of Lords.

Comment: 1) Very good answer comparing church-state relationship difference between the USA and the UK; 2) A good start covering the context of MLK speeches.  My hunch is (need more research) is that MLK sees justice in the *Biblical* sense (of righteousness toward the weak and oppressed, as the prophets would see it) instead of justice in the *secular humanist* sense (i.e. without God)

Comment: MLK primarily used the Genesis rhetoric as a unifying symbolic message, since the symbolism of the Bible would be the only ubiquitous and known by everyone.[See here for King's answer to how he felt about the U.S. Supreme Court’s decision ruling school prayer unconstitutional](https://thehumanist.com/commentary/remembering-the-humanism-of-martin-luther-king). Don't forget [many of of MLK's closest friends and associates in the Civil Rights Movement were humanists](https://religionnews.com/2012/02/22/blacks-say-atheists-were-unseen-civil-rights-heroes/).